# Environment variables for Rundeck groups in a project

Tags: rundeck

Is there a way to create global environment variables for groups in Rundeck in the same way we can create one for Projects.
For eg : project.globals.version = 123

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "really globally" variables from framework.properties file using `framework.global.myvar=myvalue` and from project.properties file using `project.globals.myvar=another_value` (for each project).

You've more info [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/config-file-reference.html#global-execution-variables).

Comment: can we do this via UI